# Prestashop Upload Product Image - Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: sql, ajax, prestashop

i'm trying made an upload image of an product. But when i'll click on the Submit button ("add archives") to send image, i receive this error on helper: **Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0**.

On the Chrome Networking tab, i receive this response of ajax call:

```
Column 'id_product' in where clause is ambiguous

        SELECT * FROM `ps_image` i INNER JOIN ps_image_shop image_shop
    ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image AND image_shop.id_shop = 1)
        WHERE `id_product` = 38
        AND image_shop.`cover`= 1 LIMIT 1
```

I'm search for this a long time, but i don't have responses.

I'm using the 1.6.0.11 version of Prestashop.

Answer (score 1):

use this query , it will remove 
**Column 'id_product' in where clause is ambiguous**
This error

```
SELECT * FROM `ps_image` i INNER JOIN ps_image_shop image_shop
    ON (image_shop.id_image = i.id_image AND image_shop.id_shop = 1)
        WHERE i.`id_product` = 38
        AND image_shop.`cover`= 1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I did, but i receive the same error...
I'm trying for a long time fix this error...

Comment: Can you share you admin detail or ftp so i can check and fix it ?

Comment: @JulioRodrigues It is working. Try to run query directly in phpMyAdmin.